# get image path of selected image javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, scripting, cloud

I am trying to upload files in the cloud, but for this to work, I need to allow users to select any image from their local machine. This means, not hard coding the path of the image. I cannot find a way online to do this. I am using nodejs as backend, but if their is a way to use front end js scripting to get the path of a selected image, I would be open to that. Here's my front end code

```
 <label for="image">SELECT IMAGE</label>
  <input type="file" name="image" required/>
```

its very basic, but with this, I was thinking using a script to get the path would be good. I need to use it for Cloudinary cloud storage on user upload. My backend code (although I probably don't need to show it, here it is for reference and to get a full understanding)

```
const data = {
            image: req.query.image,
          }
          console.log(data.image)
          // upload image here
          cloudinary.uploader.upload(data.image)
          .then((result) => {
              console.log(result.secure_url)
```

Comment: Why would you need an arbitrary image path in an arbitrary machine?

Comment: for some reason, in my code where I actually upload the image, `cloudinary.uploader.upload(data.image)`, I receive the error `"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"open","path":`. Basically unless I force the path before data.image, like so: `cloudinary.uploader.upload('./public/css/img/' + data.image)`, it will not work. This is a problem when users will be uploading images from their own local machines.

Comment: It looks like you've to store the user uploaded image on your server, then use that path when calling `.upload` instead of the image itself. You can't get the original path from the user's machine, it's obfuscated for a good reason. And it's also meaningless, your back-end code can't follow the path back to the user's machine anyway.

Comment: https://wicg.github.io/file-system-access/#api-showdirectorypicker

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers will not allow you to get the local path of an image, or any file. It is a **security risk** that could expose the client file structure, among other things.

***Try uploading an image after running the snippet below***. We are attempting to retrieve the local path using `input.value`. - By default, the image path is prepended with `C:\fakepath\` before the file name as a security measure.

```js
var fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
var path = document.getElementById("path");
var obPath = document.getElementById("obPath");
    
fileInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
  changeImage(this);
});

function changeImage(input) {
  var reader;

  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      path.innerHTML = input.value;
      obPath.innerHTML = e.target.result;
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Image Path:</p>
<p id="path"></p>
<br><br>
<p>Obfuscated Path:</p>
<p id="obPath"></p>
<br><br>
<input type="file" id="fileInput">
```

Additionally, I've also added an obfuscated path using the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) object and the [readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) method that will output a Base64 encoded URL of the local image being uploaded.

**Reason for including Base64 URL string:**

Alternatively, for your use-case you could use `nodeJS` to decode the base64-encoded part of the URL and write that out to a new file. You can then store that path in your database.